# In place modification of matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, data.table, copy-on-write

I there any way to avoid copy-on-modify for in-place modifications of matrices in `R`?

I am trying to copy a smaller matrix to a slice of larger matrix as follows.

```
library(data.table)
y <- matrix(c(11,21,31,12,22,32),nrow=3,ncol=2)
address(y)
[1] "08429190"

y[2:3,] <- matrix(c(1,1,8,12),nrow=2)
address(y)
[1] "0E033D28"
```

Comment: that returns the same address on my comp (and with prefix "0x").

Comment: When I try the above commands using `address` from the data.table package or from the pryr package I get the same address for the two instances above.  Suggest you try a newer version of R.  Also please provide self contained code samples including library calls.

Comment: Using `data.table::address`, I get the same behavior as OP. (R 3.2.0 , RStudio 0.99.441, Windows 8.0,data.table 1,9,5). But, with R console, I it returns the same address. So, the problem is with RStudio.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get the same behaviour as the OP using R 3.2.0 running within RStudio 0.99.441 on Windows 8.1 and using `pryr::address`. The issue is RStudio has a reference to y for its Environment pane. As often the case, [Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#modification) has some excellent documentation of this.

I don't think there's any way around this for matrices in the global environment other than not using RStudio. I've tried a couple of other things. Matrices within a function are fine:

```
library("pryr")
fn <- function() {
  y <- matrix(c(11,21,31,12,22,32),nrow=3,ncol=2)
  print(address(y))
  y[2:3,] <- matrix(c(1,1,8,12),nrow=2)
  print(address(y))
}
```

Calling `fn()` should show that the address is unchanged.

However, creating y as a member of a list or environment which are in the global environment doesn't prevent the copy on write (e.g. `x <- new.env(); x$y <- matrix(...)`).

Per [Is there any way to disable environment pane in RStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773472/is-there-any-way-to-disable-environment-pane-in-rstudio) there doesn't seem to be any way of disabling the environment pane.

`data.table` still manages to avoid unncessarily copies. Try:

```
library("data.table")
x <- as.data.table(matrix(c(11,21,31,12,22,32),nrow=3,ncol=2))
address(x)
x[2:3, `:=`(V1 = c(1, 1), V2 = c(8, 12))]
address(x)
x[, V3 := V1 + V2]
address(x)
```